# Regex replace wrap element html

Tags: regex

I want to replace a wrap element with another with regex and I can't get it.

HTML: `<div class="excelFormula"><code>any code</code></div>`

Replace (ideal result): `<pre><code>any code</code></pre>`

Here I leave the screenshot of what I have tried but it works for me

[image: screenshot]

Comment: *"wrap element with another"* - you have to explain exactly the rule, which elements to replace and with which elements. Otherwise, we have no idea what is in your mind.

Comment: Sure, need remplace this: "<div class="excelFormula"><code>any code</code></div>" to "<pre><code>any code</code></pre>" with Regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct, you just have to replace with `<pre>$1</pre>`.

Regular expression:

```js
/<div\b[^<>\/]*>\s*(<code.+<\/code>)\s*<\/div>/
```

Example HTML:

```html
<div class="excelFormula">  <code>any <div>code</div></code>  </div>
```

Replace with:
`<pre>$1</pre>`

Result:

```html
<pre><code>any <div>code</div></code></pre>
```

You didn't say in which programming language this will be applied but it should be universal.
URL for testing: https://regex101.com/r/9IGbj8/1

Next time please provide your solution **as text** so we don't have to type it from the screenshot.